# lapply is not working for this subsetting

Tags: r

I am working in creating a class and applying its own methods. I create a class like this:

```
make_LD1.data.frame<-function(data){structure(list(id=data$id,
                              `visit=data1$visit,
                               room=data1$room,
                               value=data1$value,
                               timepoint=data1$timepoint),
                              class=c("LongitudinalData"))}
```

and now that I have it in "LongitudinalData" I want to apply a method of this class which subset a member of the ID (ie 14) and return the data (all variables ) for this particular ID. I am doing that by this:

```
subject.LongitudinalData<-function(data, n=c(14, 20, 41, 44, 46, 54, 64, 74, 104, 106)) 
    {structure(lapply(data, function(x) x[which (data$id==n)]),
                    class = c("subject", "LongitudinalData", "data.frame"))}
```

The problem is that when I want to see the data for ie subject(ss, 14) it did not return me nothing.

I dont know what i am doing wrong...

If I do  `str(subject(ss, 14))` it gives me back the structure but if I apply:
 `dim(subject(ss,14))` it gives me back: `[1] 0 5`

Another try is when I applied split ie:

```
ss.by.condition <- split(ss, ss$room)  where ss<-subject(ss,14)
```

It gives me back: `Error in x$id[[c(1)]] : subíndice fuera de  los límites`

What is going on?? what is the problem??

```
> str(data1)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 120877 obs. of 5 variables:
$ id : int 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 ...
$ visit : int 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ room : chr "bedroom" "bedroom" "bedroom" "bedroom" ...
$ value : num 6 6 2.75 2.75 2.75 2.75 6 6 2.75 2.75 ...
$ timepoint: int 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=List of 2
   ..$ cols :List of 5
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Try `x[which(data$id==n),]` (note the comma). As is, you are subsetting *columns*, not *rows*.

Comment: side note: it is a good idea to use names that aren't existing functions. For example, `dat` instead of `data` for a data.frame/dataset.

Comment: @akrun, what exactly do you need and I will show it..

Comment: @r2evans look it `dd<-lapply(x, function(x) x[which(x$id==14), ]) ` and I received back  `Error in x$id : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: @EvanFriedland  I change it and it doesn`t work... thanks

Comment: You meant @r2evans lol

Comment: I have no idea, and I'm unable to do anything more without any sample data.

Comment: sorry @EvanFriedland lol!!!!

Comment: Ok @r2evans here is the structure of the data:

Comment: Ok @r2evans here is the structure of the data: ´str(data1) Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       120877 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id       : int  14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 ...
 $ visit    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ room     : chr  "bedroom" "bedroom" "bedroom" "bedroom" ...
 $ value    : num  6 6 2.75 2.75 2.75 2.75 6 6 2.75 2.75 ...
 $ timepoint: int  53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62  $ timepoint: int  53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=List of 2
  ..$ cols   :List of 5´

it is my initial data and I applied everything that I comment b4

Comment: use `dput(head(data1))` to make a reproducible example

Comment: Do you mean to reference both `data` and `data1` in your first function? It's admittedly very unclear to me what `class`ing this as "LongitudinalData"; why remove the `data.frame` class when it appears you still want to access data as if it is a frame? In order to do anything, the `str` output needs to be either augmented (so that we have enough elements in each vector) or truncated (to trim the longer vectors down to 4 elements); having (as @Sotos suggested) `dput(head(data1))` would help, as would having you specify what you think the output should look like (it is not clear).

Comment: Hi guys, first time this week that I can check this, In this afternoon I will work with all your suggestions. I also create a repository in case that you want to see with more precision the problems... [https://github.com/matei84/R_programming.git] @r2evans   thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Hi guys, first time this week that I can check this, In this afternoon I will work with all your suggestions. I also create a repository in case that you want to see with more precision the problems... [https://github.com/matei84/R_programming.git]  @EvanFriedland  --> thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Hi guys, first time this week that I can check this, In this afternoon I will work with all your suggestions. I also create a repository in case that you want to see with more precision the problems... [https://github.com/matei84/R_programming.git] @sotos  --> thanks for your help!!!